# How to get file path from URI in Android N

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

How can I get the file path from Uri when I open a video file from file explore.

Uri host is "content" and "_data" return null.

I want to get other videos in the same directory thus i have to get the file path.if have any other way to get videos in the same directory without file path,it also work for me.
Thanks a lot for your any ideas and solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. It works for me in Oreo as well.

```
/**
 * Method for return file path of Gallery image/ Document / Video / Audio
 *
 * @param context - context of the application or class
 * @param uri - uri to get the path
 * @return          - path of the selected image file from gallery
 */
public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri)
{
    // check here to KITKAT or new version
    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri))
    {
        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri))
        {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type))
            {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                        + split[1];
            }
        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri))
        {
            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);

            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"),
                    Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri))
        {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;

            if ("image".equals(type))
            {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }
            else if ("video".equals(type))
            {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }
            else if ("audio".equals(type))
            {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { split[1] };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection,
                    selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme()))
    {
        // Return the remote address
        if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
            return uri.getLastPathSegment();

        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme()))
    {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
 * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
 *
 * @param context           - The context.
 * @param uri               - The Uri to query.
 * @param selection         - (Optional) Filter used in the query.
 * @param selectionArgs     - (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
 * @return                  - The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
 */
private static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri,
                                   String selection, String[] selectionArgs)
{
    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = { column };

    try
    {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection,
                selection, selectionArgs, null);

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(index);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * @param uri      - The Uri to check.
 * @return         - Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
 */
private static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri)
{
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri       - The Uri to check.
 * @return          - Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
 */
private static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri)
{
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri       - The Uri to check.
 * @return          - Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
 */
private static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri)
{
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri       - The Uri to check.
 * @return          - Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
 */
private static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri)
{
    return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}
```

This code requires the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

This permission should be requested from the user at runtime as it is a dangerous permission.

Answer (score 0):

**Activity code:**

```
Uri muri;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    muri = getUriForFile("your activity", BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", "file path");
} else {
    muri = Uri.fromFile("file path");
}
```